# About elegant Reedy categories

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-categories

I discovered today the notion of elegant Reedy category introduced in the paper *Reedy categories and the $\Theta$-construction* of Julia E. Bergner and Charles Rezk. An interesting property of such categories is the following (quoting nlab [elegant Reedy category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/elegant+Reedy+category)):

if $R$ is an elegant Reedy category and $M$ is a model category in which the cofibrations are exactly the monomorphisms, then the Reedy model structure and the injective model structure on $M^{R^{op}}$ coincide.

This is stated in Proposition 3.15 of the paper of Bergner and Rezk for $M$ being a simplicial set-valued presheaf.

I was wondering if it would be possible to obtain a kind of dual statement of this, something like

"if $R$ is a "coelegant" Reedy category and $M$ is a model category in which the fibrations are exactly the epimorphisms, then the Reedy model structure and the projective model structure on $M^{R^{op}}$ coincide".

At first sight it seems possible to do so, but I may have missed something.

Comment: I'm not sure. My gut is warning me that it might be hard to construct model structures on presheaves because in your dual situation you could lose cofibrantly generated. When dualizing it's tempting to work with fibrantly generated instead, but the cosmall object argument almost never works because there are almost never cosmall objects. But maybe that's not a problem here because everything uses simplicial sets? I really don't know.

Comment: Another point is that the 3.14 feels a lot like the pushout product axiom, so it's dual should be a statement about a map of hom objects being a fibration. But that holds without dualizing the whole model structure, i.e. it already holds in the case where cofibrations are monomorphisms. If you change the fibrations then you have to re-prove this (to see that projective fibrations are coelegant fibrations) and I don't immediately see how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, I think the statement that you quoted from the nLab is wrong.  It was copied from v1 of the Bergner-Rezk paper, but v2 corrected the statement to be only about *simplicial* presheaves on $R$ (although I think the proof would probably work for presheaves on $R$ with values in any other presheaf category).  I've just fixed the nLab as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I remember this question throwing me for a loop last year and it's good to see it resolved. Any thoughts on Sinan's proposed notion of a `coelegant' Reedy category? Is it possible to define such a thing and to prove the dual of Theorem 1 in the new nLab version as Sinan wanted?

Comment: I kind of doubt it, since Set is very not self-dual.

Comment: @DavidWhite, I wrote out a version of the proof at http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/elegant+Reedy+category which implies that the statement holds for presheaves value in any Cisinski model category.  Clearly a lot of non-self-dual properties are used.

Comment: Thanks. I think that completely resolves Sinan's question, and it's nice to have a full proof written out on that page.